# Simulate closed laptop on windows

Tags: windows-10, laptop, mouse, power, automation

I have an automation script that needs to use my mouse. This means that my laptop's display is always on. I would like a way to turn off the laptop screen such that the simulated mouse movements will not turn it on again (simulating using python mouse module).

One way I've found to do this is to set "Close lid action: " to "Do nothing".

The problem is, this means I have to actually close my screen. I'd like it to be open to allow for air to move to cool the computer a bit. Is it possible to simulate a closed screen on windows?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: can i have more details on why it's not clear?

Comment: John - Ignore the bot comment. It's unfathomable, a comment auto-added at question review, often by people who seemingly have no clue, yet feel compelled to push the right buttons to advance their 'progress' through the early stages of reputation gain on stack exchange. You can't reply to it & whoever left it may never even come back to see what eventually happened. Questions have been raised about its lack of detail & how it confuses new users. If someone with a clue needs detail, they will have to ask specifically what detail they need. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you'd be happy with the lid open but the machine thinking it's closed…
You can usually fool a laptop into thinking its lid is closed by placing a magnet somewhere on the front edge of the keyboard surround. So long as you don't have an old spinny rust HD near that spot, all will be fine.
You can probably detect the location by using a paperclip on the top edge of the screen, then place the magnet on the opposite face, as if closed.